# How to test redirect_to without making a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, specifications

I would like to test if a private method from application_controller `redirect_to` proper path. Here is what I tried to do:

```
  describe 'application is complete' do
    it 'redirects to the mortgage application show page' do
      controller.send(:load_mortgage_application)
      expects(controller).to receive(:redirect_to).with(mortgage_application_path(controller.locale, mortgage_application))
    end
  end
```

But I get error:

```
  RuntimeError:
ActionController::RackDelegation#status= delegated to @_response.status=, but @_response is nil: ...
```

How can I test it without having a response?

// THIS WORKS:

```
    it 'redirects to the mortgage application show page' do
      controller.expects(:redirect_to).with(mortgage_application_path(controller.locale, mortgage_application))
      controller.send(:load_mortgage_application)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would assume you need to be within a controller spec, so that you could, for instance, use get :load_mortgage_application. At that point you can do:

```
response.should redirect_to '/scorecard'
```

or the newer syntax:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to '/scorecard'
```

Comment: The thing is that's a private method. I know it's not the best practice to test implementation, but for some reason I want to do that. `response` is `nil` until I make a request, and I don't make a request, because application controller doesn't have any action, only `before_filter`s.

Comment: Ahh, didn't catch that before.